# Magento 2 : Add custom text in invoice pdf header

Tags: magento-2.1

I need to add custom text below the Invoice No and before the Order No. I have tried with modifying insertDocumentNumber() method in  `vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Pdf/AbstractPdf.php`. I have printed it but it is overlapping on the Invoice No label. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to edit just below three line in AbstractPdf.php

Replace line 391

```
$page->drawRectangle(25, $top, 570, $top - 70);
```

Instead of

```
$page->drawRectangle(25, $top, 570, $top - 55);
```

Replace line 397

```
$page->drawText(__('Order # ') . $order->getRealOrderId(), 35, $top -= 45, 'UTF-8');
```

instead of

```
$page->drawText(__('Order # ') . $order->getRealOrderId(), 35, $top -= 30, 'UTF-8');
```

Additional add after line no 621

```
$page->drawText('My Sample Text', 35, $docHeader[1] - 30, 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: Tried with your solution. Now it is showing "My Sample Text" label but it is not showing Invoice No label.

Comment: did you update any code except above ?, may be line number is mismatch, 
can you check similar word and replace with that

Comment: Hey Dhaval Thank you very much. It worked like a magic. Actually first I made mistake. I have replaced line 621 with above line hence Invoice label was missing. Now if I want to change position of this custom text below Order No or Order Date, do I need to change only top position $top?

Comment: @Mahesh , You're Welcome. if you want to print this custom text after order number or order date then need to add this line `$page->drawText(__('My Sample Test '), 35, $top -= 30, 'UTF-8');` after line number 398 and change position `$top -= 30` in this line according to up down

Comment: Ok thanks. I am new to this so facing problems. One more thing I have made this change in core file directly. I think I need to create new file and override with new code? Or it is fine?

Comment: Its better to override this file :)

Comment: Hey Man @Dhaval, Great Job, Saved My Time as Well..

Comment: @Anup, Most Welcome

Answer (score 2):

try to override

```
Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\AbstractPdf
```

and use

```
$page->drawText(__('custom text # ') . 'value', 35, $top -= 30, 'UTF-8');
```

well, in this case you will need to make some changes in position of text but it will work. Give a thumbs up if its helpful.